# Typeahead.js autocomplete not showing any sugestions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

I know that here there are many similar questions like my question. what I need is help to analyze where my mistake.
you can see my code in [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/EsGun/1b8a5ber/2/).

as you can see, I created a form with autocomplete, when i clik field "Kode" there no sugestion from typeahead

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#kode').typeahead({
      source: function(query, process) {
        objects = [];
        var data = [
            {"kode":"X1","nama":"XL REG NASIONAL"},
            {"kode":"X10","nama":"XL REG NASIONAL"},
            {"kode":"X100","nama":"XL REG NASIONAL"},
            {"kode":"X15","nama":"XL REG NASIONAL"},
            {"kode":"X25","nama":"XL REG NASIONAL"},
            {"kode":"X30","nama":"XL REG NASIONAL"}
            ];
       
        $.each(data, function(i, object) {
          objects.push(object.kode + '#' + object.nama);
        });

        process(objects);
      },
      updater: function (item) {
        var s = item.split('#');
        return s[0];
      },
      matcher: function (item) {
        var s = item.split('#');
        return s[0].toLowerCase().indexOf(this.query.toLowerCase()) != -1
      },
      highlighter: function (item) {
        var s = item.split('#');
        var regex = new RegExp( '(' + this.query + ')', 'gi' );
        return s[0].replace(regex, "<strong>$1</strong>");
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>
<form class="form-horizontal" id="form-point">
 <div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Kode</label>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
   <input type="text" id="kode" name="kode" class="form-control" autofocus="autofocus">
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Keterangan</label>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="keterangan" name="keterangan" readonly="readonly">
   </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Point</label>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
   <input type="text" id="point" name="point" class="form-control">         </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: where do you see that the `source` can accept function? [here](http://www.runningcoder.org/jquerytypeahead/documentation#options-source) it says that source can accept {object|array}

Comment: when i search tutorial for use json object in typeahead i found it in [here](http://tatiyants.com/how-to-use-json-objects-with-twitter-bootstrap-typeahead/) and [here](http://nazoftware.blogspot.co.id/2013/02/modifikasi-typeahead-bootstrap-dan-ajax.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an problem with your typeahead js file, i have used bootstrap3 typeahead js file

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/4.0.2/bootstrap3-typeahead.js"></script>

<form class="form-horizontal" id="form-point">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Kode</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input type="text" id="kode" name="kode" class="form-control" autofocus="autofocus">
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Keterangan</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="keterangan" name="keterangan" readonly="readonly">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Point</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input type="text" id="point" name="point" class="form-control">         </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Check here  : https://jsfiddle.net/1b8a5ber/4/

Comment: thanks, solved after i change the typeahead.js like your code... i downloaded it from [twiter.github.io](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/). i think it is wrong version